EnvoyFilter Rate Limiting for UI webapp on concurrent requests from any single IP
I have read about global and local rate limiting. We have requirements for rate limiting traffic to our UI pod deployed on k8s from users who may attempt DDOS. We would like to limit any single IP attempting to invoke more than 5 requests per minute but it seems like this is only possible via a memcache like redis running behind an envoy filter. Is my understanding correct or a local rate limit envoy filter would suffice without a caching mechanism running behind it?
https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#local-rate-limit

template:
  metadata:
    annotations:
      proxy.istio.io/config: |-
        proxyStatsMatcher:
          inclusionRegexps:
          - ".*http_local_rate_limit.*"

Only researching for now to test out the possible solution.

The local rate limiting is applied to each pod replica (i.e., the instance of your UI pod) individually. So, if you have an ingress controller that routes traffic to multiple UI pods behind the scenes, each one of those pods will have its rate limits.
The global rate limit applies to all pod instances, requiring you to deploy a rate-limiting service and Redis instance.
More info:

https://learncloudnative.com/blog/2022-09-08-ratelimit-istio
Local and Global rate limiting: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/other_features/other_features

